# docker commit after docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecr

I'm running docker compose as follows:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build -d
```

the contents of docker-compose.dev.yml are:

```
version: '3'

services:

  client:
    container_name: client
    build:
      context: frontend
    environment:
      - CADDY_SUBDOMAIN=xxx
      - PRIVATE_IP=xxx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - express
    volumes:
      - /home/ec2-user/.caddy:/root/.caddy

  express:
    container_name: express
    build: express
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    restart: always
```

Then I want to create images from these containers to use them in a testing server by pushing them to aws ECR and pulling on the test server, to avoid the time of creating the dockers all over again. Simply using docker commit did not worked.

what is the correct approach to creating images from outputs of docker compose?

thanks

Comment: In general, the correct approach to generating images is to use a Dockerfile. Using `docker commit` to save "live" changes results in an image that is hard to reproduce (there's no record of how it was created).

Comment: "Simply using docker commit did not worked." What happened when you tried? Were there errors, or were the resulting images not what you expected?

Comment: @larsks mainly wasnt in the network, didn't looked dipper then that. dint wants to waste time on attempted fixed of small holes when I'm not sure I'm on course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should basically never use `docker commit`.  The standard approach is to describe how to [build your images using a Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/#build-the-apps-container-image), and check that file into source control.  You can push the built image to a registry like Docker Hub, and you can check out the original source code and rebuild the image.

The good news is that you basically have this setup already.  Each of your Compose services has a `build:` block that has the data on how to build the image.  So it's enough to

```sh
docker-compose build
```

and you'll get a separate Docker image for each component.

Often if you're doing this you'll also want to push the images to some Docker registry.  In the Compose setup, you can specify an [`image:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#image) for each service as well.  If you have both `build:` and `image:`, that specifies the image name to use for the built image (otherwise Compose will pick one based on the project name).

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: frontend
    image: registry.example.com/project/frontend
    et: cetera
  express:
    build: express
    image: registry.example.com/project/express
    et: cetera
```

Then you can have Compose both build and push the images

```sh
docker-compose build
docker-compose push
```

One final technique that can be useful is to split the Compose setup into two files.  The main `docker-compose.yml` file has the setup you'd need to run the set of containers, on any system, with access to the container registry.  A separate [`docker-compose.override.yml` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files) would support developer use where you have a copy of the source code as well.  If you're using Compose for deployment, you only need to copy the main `docker-compose.yml` file to the target system.

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  client:
    image: registry.example.com/project/frontend
    ports: [...]
    environment: [...]
    restart: always
    # volumes: [...]
  express:
    image: registry.example.com/project/express
    ports: [...]
    environment: [...]
    restart: always
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.override.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  client:
    build: frontend
    # all other settings come from main docker-compose.yml
  express:
    build: express
    # all other settings come from main docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: With Dockerfile building you cannot bind-mount things. So if you wanna build a VM image using `virt-install` within `Dockerfile`, you cannot access `/dev/kvm` of the host for example.

Comment: That's true on the one hand, but on the other a Docker image will never persist changes to the host, or to external things like databases.  If you need to do things like manipulate VMs, doing it in the context of building a reusable image probably isn't the right approach.

Comment: In our case the VM is run only to install unattended a windows system to a disk image that should be within the docker container. Unfortunately we can't do that without wasting a lot of disk space with `docker run` followed by another `docker build` that copies the disk into the new image, because `COPY` doesn't handle sparse files. It will allocate 60GB of space even if only 20GB is used on the image. Workaround right now is to `RUN fallocate --dig-holes /image.qcow2` after the `COPY`, but it's ugly.

Comment: Actually I found a better way. Instead of `COPY` I do `RUN --mount=target=/context cp --sparse=always /context/vmdisk.qcow2 /image/vmdisk.qcow2`. This will also avoid needless caching.